# iOS ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: objective-c

finally I got ASI-xx stuff working so I dont get ARC compiling errors nor anything else missing.

Now I want to try ASIFormDataRequest to be able to login on a website right from the application.

This is what I alreadxy got, but it doesnt seem to work right:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    NSString *str = @"http://mysite.com/ucp.php?module=login";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"username" forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:@"password" forKey:@"password"];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
    NSLog(@"%d",[request responseStatusCode]);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com"]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

If I remove the webview nothing happens on the screen.

Here are the results of the NSLog:

```
(null)
0
```

The textfield(of the website) where I want to POST data to has the following code:

```
<input tabindex="1" name="username" id="username" size="25" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" type="text">
<input tabindex="2" name="password" id="password" size="25" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" type="text">
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your calling the method [request startAsynchronous]; This handle the request on separate from the main thread so the [request responseString]; will still be empty when it's there.

There are two things you can do.
[request startSynchronous] but this will cause your UI to stall.

The best option is:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

You already set the delegate so this should work.

A sidenote: ASIHTTPRequest is an old framework and they stopt developing for it. A good replacement is AFNetworking.

Comment: Thank you, :) now ASIHTTPRequest is cleared, but can you help me with the ASiFormDataRequest thing? :) Displayed above

Comment: The code itself looks ok. Don't know where your webview is for. And what you want to achieve. If you want to display the login result of your ASIFormDataRequest in your webview you will have to connect the request.responseString to '- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL'.

Comment: OKay, thank you. See I want to create a login view, user types his name and password, then it logs in (using ASIFormDataRequest) and then it loads, using the web view, the forum after loging in

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK but make sure that your web service is working fine using [Chrome Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).